# ASP.NET MVC 3 - getting duplicate Rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently using MVC 3 with Entity Framework 5.
So this is my controller that is called MachineController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Gestion_Machines.Models;

namespace Gestion_Machines.Controllers
{ 
    public class MachineController : Controller
    {
        private RTTV5Entities db = new RTTV5Entities();

        //
        // GET: /Machine/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.tMachines.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Machine/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(string id)
        {
            tMachines tmachines = db.tMachines.Find(id);
            return View(tmachines);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Machine/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Machine/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(tMachines tmachines)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.tMachines.Add(tmachines);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            return View(tmachines);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Machine/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            tMachines tmachines = db.tMachines.Find(id);
            return View(tmachines);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Machine/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(tMachines tmachines)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tmachines).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(tmachines);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Machine/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            tMachines tmachines = db.tMachines.Find(id);
            return View(tmachines);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Machine/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {            
            tMachines tmachines = db.tMachines.Find(id);
            db.tMachines.Remove(tmachines);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Index View that was automatically generated after creating the controller along with create, delete, details and Edit:

```
@model IEnumerable<Gestion_Machines.Models.tMachines>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<link href="../../Content/machine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            NomMachine
        </th>
        <th>
            Fabriquant
        </th>
        <th>
            MachineSection
        </th>
        <th>
            TypeMachine
        </th>
        <th>
            VitesseMaxi
        </th>
        <th>
            NbPistes
        </th>
        <th>
            UniteVitesse
        </th>
        <th>
            UniteEntrante
        </th>
        <th>
            UniteSortante
        </th>
        <th>
            Efficience
        </th>
        <th>
            EfficienceGlobale
        </th>
        <th>
            VitesseMoy
        </th>
        <th>
            TauxPanne
        </th>
        <th>
            TauxArret
        </th>
        <th>
            RunM2
        </th>
        <th>
            RunML
        </th>
        <th>
            TCO
        </th>
        <th>
            Section
        </th>
        <th>
            Atelier
        </th>
        <th>
            TransfertFocus
        </th>
        <th>
            MagasinEntree
        </th>
        <th>
            MagasinSortie
        </th>
        <th>
            NbPalettes
        </th>
        <th>
            MagasinSortieWIP
        </th>
        <th>
            MagasinSortieSF
        </th>
        <th>
            MagasinSortieFG
        </th>
        <th>
            Qualite
        </th>
        <th>
            BlistersPerCarton
        </th>
        <th>
            SeuilProdAtteint
        </th>
        <th>
            TpsChgmtOf
        </th>
        <th>
            QteProdSaisie
        </th>
        <th>
            Active
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomMachine)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fabriquant)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MachineSection)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TypeMachine)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VitesseMaxi)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NbPistes)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UniteVitesse)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UniteEntrante)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UniteSortante)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Efficience)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EfficienceGlobale)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VitesseMoy)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TauxPanne)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TauxArret)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RunM2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RunML)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TCO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Section)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Atelier)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransfertFocus)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MagasinEntree)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MagasinSortie)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NbPalettes)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MagasinSortieWIP)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MagasinSortieSF)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MagasinSortieFG)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qualite)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BlistersPerCarton)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SeuilProdAtteint)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TpsChgmtOf)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QteProdSaisie)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

So my problem is when I access `/Machine/Index` I do get the appropriate table, but somehow It contains duplicated records, while other records are missing.
I haven't changed anything in the controller or the View, both of them where generated.

ps: my database doesn't contain any duplicated ones.

edit:
I can see exactly 49 records on my table view. Basically only 3 different records where one is repeated 6 times, another is repeated 42 times and another not repeated.
On my original database table, I got exactly 49 records where there are no duplicates.

Having tried to view my Machines table from the server explorer (right click > "Show Table Data"), I got the following error:
`This Database Cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL Server version or an unsupported database compatibility.`

I'm currently searching for this error.

Comment: How many records you have in Machines table ? And how many are you seeing in your screen ?

Comment: I'm seeing 49 records in the Machines table view. Basically only 3 different ones. One of them repeated six times, another repeated 42 times and another (last one) repeated once.

In my actual database there are 49 records, where I have no duplicates.

Note: I just realized, When I tried to click "Show Table Data" in the server explorer, I get an error that says "This Database Cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL Server version or an unsupported database compatibility"
I'm looking for this issue as we speak.

Comment: The compatibility problem is solved, I now can properly show my table data in Visual studio. Although, I'm still getting duplicated rows when I execute the application. This only happens with a specific table. I'm not sure why however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had this problem a few weeks ago, it was driving me crazy until I decided to update my Visual Studio, go to `tools >  Extensions and Updates > Updates` , make sure that your VS is updated to the last version
This solved the problem for me.

Hope I helped

Comment: I just got it working, I didn't update it but I installed a recent version of VS and the problem was solved. I guess updating would've worked.. where have you been before! :)